# Renewal expired SSL certificate not being loaded Nginx

Tags: ssl, https, nginx, ssl-certificate

via Namecheap I have my SSL certificates (POSITIVESSL Comodo) which run on my Nginx webserver to offer https to my clients. This worked like a charm until my certificate expired.

Now I tried to install a new certificate, but whatever I try, the old one is being loaded.

What I did.

1. Removed all the old certificate files (.key, .crt, .csr)
2. Using [this tutorial](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=3) creating a new key files.
3. Entered that file into the Namecheap SSL panel to generate new SSL certificates (which arrived, and show to be valid from 11/26/2012 to 12/26/2013.
4. Go to my certificates directory, put in the 3 .crt files I got.
5. Using [this tutorial](http://notes.rioastamal.net/2012/04/nginx-install-comodo-positivessl.html) i bundled all the .crt files into 1 .pem file.
6. Check my nginx.conf to confirm all the paths to the .key & .pem file are correct
7. Restart nginx

I even tried to change the file names, to ensure they cannot conflict with the old ones, but still my old certificates are being loaded. I have used tools like: http://www.digicert.com/help/ to test the certs, also there the old ones are still being loaded.

Apart from Nginx, should I restart anything else to ensure the new files are being loaded correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue has been resolved, the DDOS protection proxy also needed to be updated.

Comment: Would you be able to explain this a little further? I know it's been a bit, but I'm having the exact same issue and not sure where to look for this DDOS proxy stuff. Thanks!